# Class 'Mongo' not found when using Mongor bundle in Laravel

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, mongor

**Problem:** When using the `mongor` bundle for Laravel, I get an error `Class 'Mongo' not found`. Any ideas what went wrong?

I installed mongodb and started the mongodb service. Next I installed the [mongor bundle](http://bundles.laravel.com/bundle/mongor) and created/updated the following files.

```
php artisan bundle:install mongor
```

**bundles.php**

```
return array(
    'docs' => array('handles' => 'docs'),
    'mongor' => array('auto' => true),
);
```

**database.php**

```
'default' => 'mongor',

'mongor' => array(
    'hostname'   => 'localhost',
    'connect'    => true,
    'timeout'    => '',
    'replicaSet' => '',
    'db'         => 'test',
    'username'   => '',
    'password'   => '',
),
```

**user.php**

```
<?php

class User extends Mongor\Model {}
```

**routes.php**

```
Route::get('test', function() {
    $user = User::find(1);
});
```

**ERROR**

```
Class 'Mongo' not found
Location: /var/www/test/bundles/mongor/mongodb.php on line 85
```

**Line causing error**

```
$this->_connection = new \Mongo($conn, $options);
```

Comment: It is probably `new \MongoClient($conn, $options)` if you just installed the driver, you are probably using an old tutorial

Comment: Yup I just installed `mongodb`, I did not install any drivers (`mongo.so`? is it required?) and only installed the Mongodb library for my framework. I changed the erroneous line to `$this->_connection = new \MongoClient($conn, $options);` and get the similar error `Class 'Mongor\MongoClient' not found`

Comment: Oh yes you need to install a driver in order to connect to MongoDB, just like you would with SQL, check this out: http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php

Comment: Thanks that works, restarted `mongodb` service and getting the error: `Failed to connect to: localhost:27017: Authentication failed on database 'test' with username '': auth fails`

Comment: You are trying to use auth on your connection when MongoDB has no auth enabled, most likely your ORM has a config file with this in. Just delete those bits

Comment: Right on, successfully connected to MongoDB :)

Comment: Awesome sauce, glad to have helped :)

Comment: If this is solved now is there a way you can mark it as such?

Comment: @Sammaye Would you like to write an answer to this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you don't have a driver installed.

In order to connect to MongoDB you must have the PHP driver which will allow you to communicate to MongoDBs interface.

You cna find the installation guide in the PHP manual ( http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php ) or on the MongoDB website ( http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/php/ ).

Make sure to start MongoDB with auth turned off for your case.